# Bazel build error, to use graph transform to reduce the size of .pb model

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

A question when I was trying to use command Bazel build to build TensorFlow. After I entered this command:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph
```

The compile started, and about 3 minutes later, it said
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmhbn.png) (below you can see I check my cudnn and cuda version)

Anyone could help me with this?

Comment: Can you provide details on our used operating system and Bazel version?

Answer (score 1):

**Works on my machine**

Just did a checkout of TensorFlow:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
```

Then build the target (using [bazelisk](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazelisk)):

```
bazelisk build tensorflow/tools/graph_transforms:transform_graph
```

The build of the target succeeds:

```
INFO: Elapsed time: 2111.652s, Critical Path: 293.22s
INFO: 5811 processes: 5811 local.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 5969 total actions
```

CUDA version check:

`cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt` gives me `CUDA Version 10.0.130`

`bazelisk version` gives me `1.1.0`

```
lsb_release -a
```

results in:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

**Your machine**

There is an error reported:

```
unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_36'
```

It seems that `nvcc` cannot compile your CUDA code, since the define GPU architecture is not supported.

Also, Bazel advises you to use the `--verbose_failures` flag to get more details about our error.